# Customize SOAP response in ASMX webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

this is the response after calling my webservice

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><unregisterResponse xmlns="ns2=http://gate.com"><unregisterResult><returncode>1</returncode><returndesc>SUCCESS</returndesc></unregisterResult></unregisterResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

First, I want to remove the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` in `soap:Envelope`

Second, I want to change `unregisterResponse` into `ns2:return` with that namespace

Thirdly, I want to change `soap:Envelop` and `soap:Body` to `S:Envelop` and `S:Body`

For finally they look like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:unregisterResponse xmlns:ns2="http://gate.com"><return><returncode>1</returncode><returndesc>SUCCESS</returndesc></return></unregisterResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

What I tried:

- I tried to put `[XmlRoot("return")]` on top of my return class, but in my service there multiple return classes, I can only name 1 class as `return`
- I tried `[XmlRoot("return", Namespace = "http://gate.com/unregister")]` for fixing error above but `<return>` becomes `<return xmlns="http://gate.com/unregister">` with xmlns, which our operator not allow

Please help me to solve this, thank you.